# What exactly is stopping this script from working in IE8? (IE8 Issue)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, navigation, sliding

javascript is not my forte, I found a navigation script that is designed exactly the way I want it (Jsfiddle below), but I cannot get it to work with IE8 (the best browser ever *sarcasm*).

Please Help!

http://jsfiddle.net/JSjY4/1/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var fine = [36, 34, 34, 34];
    var mitms = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');
    var l0 = (mitms[0].offsetLeft + fine[0]);
    document.getElementById("nav_arrow").style.marginLeft = l0 + "px";

    for (var i = 0; i < mitms.length; i++) {

        mitms[i].fine = fine[i];

        mitms[i].onclick = function() {
            arr(this);
            var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');


        }
    }

};

function arr(el) {
    var mitms = document.getElementsByClassName('mitm');
    var l = el.offsetLeft + el.fine;
    document.getElementById("nav_arrow").style.marginLeft = l + "px";
}
```

Comment: `default` is a reserved word, and older browsers didn't allow reserved words as  identifiers for object properties. Use `this["default"]` instead, or change the property name.

Comment: Alright, so now you changed the question. IE also doesn't support `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Crazy Train I actually forgot to test it without the defaults, so I got rid of them and it still works in chrome etc.. but not IE8, any ideas to what is breaking the code for ie8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `default` as a variable name, as it is [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).
Just use a different name instead.

From the [documentation](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1) (7.6.1.1 Keywords),

> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as Identifiers in ECMAScript programs:
>       break,
>       do,
>       instanceof,
>       typeof,
>       case
>       else,
>       new,
>       var,
>       catch,
>       finally,
>       return,
>       void,
>       continue,
>       for,
>       switch,
>       while,
>       debugger,
>       function,
>       this,
>       with,
>       **default**,
>       if,
>       throw,
>       delete,
>       in,
>       try

Edit:
As @CrazyTrain said, `document.getElementsByClassName` is not supported.  You could replace it with a shim like this:

```
function getElementsByClassName(needle) {
    var my_array = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var retvalue = new Array();
    var i;
    var j;
    for (i=0,j=0;i<my_array.length;i++) {
        var c = " " + my_array[i].className + " ";
        if (c.indexOf(" " + needle + " ") != -1) retvalue[j++] = my_array[i];
    }
    return retvalue;
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
var mitms = getElementsByClassName('mitm');
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, Ill need to fiddle with this a little to get it to work, this is a bit over my head :)

Comment: Does JS fiddle have issues using the shim, because I tried to implement it, but it does not seem to work?

Comment: I updated the shim (using one from http://daniel.glazman.free.fr/weblog/newarchive/2003_06_01_glazblogarc.html#s95320189) and showed how to use it.

Comment: I just got a work around for it dropping the tag entirely http://jsfiddle.net/emosquito/9ZWAg/11/